# Google sheet Record date cell is edited to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just need this code modified to put the date values on another sheet instead of offsetting to another column.

This code records the time when a cell is edited and offsets it to another column.

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var capture = sheet.getActiveCell();
if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") //sheet name
if(capture.getColumn() == 14 ) {
var add = capture.offset(0, 22); //"0" is the line in reference the cell updated, ''0'' same line, "1" reference at column "1" is 1 column to the right.
var data = new Date();
  data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT+8:00","HH:mm:ss");
add.setValue(data);
}

}
```

The date should show up on another sheet. Instead of on the same sheet.

Comment: What is the question? Have you already tried to modified the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==14) {
    var ash=e.source.getSheetByName('Another Sheet');//You need to set the other sheet name
    ash.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+8:00","HH:mm:ss"));//I am putting it into the same row/column on the other sheet.
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hey it works! Although it says: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")
Thank you so much you are a lifesaver!

Comment: You cannot run the function from Script Editor as it requires an event object like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)  When I debug these things I always trigger them with an onEdit(e) trigger by editing the appropriate sheet.

Comment: Uhm okay. It's working fine though. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Not unless you wish to change the other sheets range.